# Update array Object and display it in collectionView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a list of machine name and type in tableView and when user click it, it push into detailVC.

At first the the user don't have an image, than user choose an image from gallery and return it as a PHAssets.

Than I convert the PHAssets into data and show it in collectionView, so I create an array of data and display it in collectionView.

Than I want to update MachineItem object to my data from PHAssets, since in MachineItem object have an array of Data.

So when user return from machine list in tableView, the object already update. But when I tap the list from tableView. The photo I save in an object is not showing, how can display it in my collectionView.

This is my Model

```
struct MachineItem: Codable {
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var type: String
    var qrNumber = Int.random(in: 1..<10)
    var maintenanceDate: String?
    var images: [Data]?
}
```

This is my MachineStore class that perform all add, update, and remove object from MachineItem

```
class MachineStore {
    
    var items: [MachineItem] = []
    
    @discardableResult func add(_ machine: MachineItem, at index: Int) -> MachineItem {
        let newMachine = MachineItem(id: machine.id, name: machine.name, type: machine.type, qrNumber: machine.qrNumber, maintenanceDate: machine.maintenanceDate, images: machine.images)
        
        items.insert(newMachine, at: index)
        
        return newMachine
    }
    
    func update(_ machine: MachineItem) {
        if let index = items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == machine.id }) {
            items[index].name = machine.name
            items[index].type = machine.type
            items[index].qrNumber = machine.qrNumber
            items[index].maintenanceDate = machine.maintenanceDate
            items[index].images = machine.images
        }
    }
    
    @discardableResult func remove(at index: Int) -> MachineItem {
        return items.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

This is my MachineDataVC that have a list of MachineItem Object in TableView

```
class MachineDataVC: UIViewController {
    
    var tableView = UITableView()
    var store = MachineStore()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = store.items[indexPath.row]
        
        let detailVC = MachineDetailVC()
        detailVC.item = item
        detailVC.store = store
        navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
        
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And this is the detailVC where I can't display the images data when back and fort from MachineDataVC to detailVC

```
class MachineDetailVC: UIViewController {
    var item: MachineItem!
    var store: MachineStore!
    var images: [Data] = []

    var photoCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // CollectionView setup
        photoCollectionView.delegate = self
        photoCollectionView.dataSource = self
        photoCollectionView.register(MachineDetailCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MachineDetailCell.cellID)
        photoCollectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }

    // This where PHAssets being retrieve
    @objc func pickPhotos() {
        let imagePickerVC = ImagePickerController()
        imagePickerVC.settings.selection.max = 10
        imagePickerVC.settings.theme.selectionStyle = .numbered
        imagePickerVC.settings.fetch.assets.supportedMediaTypes = [.image]
        imagePickerVC.settings.selection.unselectOnReachingMax = true

        self.presentImagePicker(imagePickerVC) { (assets) in
            
        } deselect: { (_) in
            
        } cancel: { (_) in
            
        } finish: { (assets) in
            self.images = self.getImage(from: assets)
            self.photoCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    private func getImage(from assets: [PHAsset]) -> [Data] {
        let images = assets.map { fetchImage(from: $0) }
        print("Pick image:", images)
        return images
    }
    
    private func fetchImage(from asset: PHAsset) -> Data {
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.isSynchronous = true
        
        var thumbnail = Data()
        
        manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: .init(width: 100, height: 100), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options) { (result, info) in
            if let selectedImage = result?.data {
                thumbnail = selectedImage
            }
        }
        return thumbnail
    }

    // This is how I setup collectionView
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MachineDetailCell.cellID, for: indexPath) as! MachineDetailCell
        let image = images[indexPath.row]

        cell.set(imageData: image)
        
        return cell
    }

    // This is how I save the object from UIBarButtonItem
    @objc func saveItem() {
        guard let name = machineNameTF.text else { return }
        guard let type = machineTypeTF.text else { return }
        guard let date = machineMaintenanceDateTF.text else { return }
        
        let machineItem = MachineItem(id: item.id, name: name, type: type, qrNumber: item.qrNumber, maintenanceDate: date, images: images)
        
        store.update(machineItem)
    }
}
```

What I've been trying so far is like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if !images.isEmpty {
           return store.items.count
        } else {
           return images.count
        }
    }
```

I'm very glad if anyone can help me :)

Comment: can you share more code of your MachineDetailVC this seems fine have setup collection view datasource

Comment: Hey @Abhishek can you give me a hint what more code of MachineDetailVC, because my ui was setup programmatically. I'm afraid there will too much code when I edit the question.

Comment: show us how you setup your collection view

Comment: I update the question @Abhishek :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my answer from my question, what I need to do is in my viewDidLoad I need to add in my MachineDetailVC

```
self.images = self.item.images ?? []
```

since when I save the data back into items in machineStore, I need to give the data into images array in MachineDetailVC